# php code as converted in asp.net not working as expected?

Tags: c#, javascript, php, asp.net, ajax

Doing example of `Ajax`, a user type in textbox and its text is continuously posted back using javascript and simultanously showing result whether the item available or not.

main **html** look is as

```
 <body>
            <h3>The chuff Bucket </h3>
            Enter the food you like to order:
            <input type="text" id="userInput" onfocus="process()"/>
            <div id="underInput"/>
 </body>
```

Here is my code for javascript

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();    

function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp) {
        alert("cant create that object boss!");
    } else
        return xmlHttp;

}


function process() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.aspx?food=" + food, true);

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send(null);

    } else {
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span style = "color:blue;">' + message + '</span>';
            setTimeout('process()', 1000);
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }
    }
}
```

The code for php is working fine which is

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
     $food = $_GET['food'];
     $foodArray = array("tuna","bacon","beef","mutton","biryani");

     if($food == '')
         echo 'Enter a food you idiot.';
     else{
         if(in_array($food,$foodArray))
          echo 'We do have '.$food.'!';
         else
          echo 'We do not sell '.$food.'!';
     }
echo '</response>';
?>
```

But when converted to asp.net it is postback and and working but not showing the reult inside the div. Main cause which i figure out relating echo lines

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("<response>");
            string food = (string)Request.QueryString["food"];

            string[] foodArray = new string[] { "tuna", "beef", "mutton", "fish","biryani" };

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(food))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Enter a food you idiot.");
            }
            else 
            {
                if (foodArray.Contains(food))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("We serve " + food);
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("We do not serve " + food);
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("</response>");

        }
```

**Note:** i have tried instead of `Print` `Response.Write` but the result is same the div with id=underInput not getting the result. Anyone here help please.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have replaced all System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print with Response.Write.  Then, check the HTML markup on foodstore.aspx.

Foodstore.aspx should have the @Page directive, but nothing else..  You want to return XML content, so you need to make sure there are no DOCTYPE or HTML elements on your page.